# Multiple superclasses in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

Can I inherit from multiple classes in Objective-C? (If yes, how so?)

Comment: Pretty sure objective-c doesn't have multiple inheritance.

Comment: It doesn't, but this is a perfectly valid question.  No need to downvote (I upvoted to balance the -1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have said, Objective-C is single-inheritance. However, [protocols](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#protocols) provide handy ways to get around any type of situation you might have wanted multiple inheritance for and they allow you to avoid pitfalls that multiple inheritance creates such as [The Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem).

Edit: Changes interface to protocol. Sorry, getting Java and Obj-C mixed up.

Comment: Huh? "interface" is just the class declaration in Obj-C.

Comment: Editing original posting. Got my terminology mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

No, Objective-C is single-inheritance only.

Consider looking at [protocols](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#protocols) which are a way of exposing a declared interface from a class. It's not the same as multiple inheritance, but solves some needs.